# Definitive List of NetBeans Shortcuts

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

I'm looking for a list of helpful NetBeans shortcuts. Examples include: CTRL+clicking on a method to go to it's definition and using CTRL+Space for intellisense.

Feel free to list your favorites here or send me a link(s). FYI - I primarily use NetBeans for PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Top 10 NetBeans IDE Keyboard Shortcuts I use the most](http://netbeanside61.blogspot.com/2008/04/top-10-netbeans-ide-keyboard-shortcuts.html)

I have written a list of shortcuts some years ago for Java IDE part of NetBeans IDE.  Many more shortcuts are listed in comments of that post.  Even if these shortcuts are for Java many of these these shortcuts can also be used in PHP IDE.

Answer (score 4):

http://www.symfony-zone.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/symfony_php_cheatsheet.pdf
http://offtheline.net/assets/2007/12/11/netbeans_ror.pdf

http://www.phpmag.ru/2009/01/23/extremely-usefull-netbeans-shortcuts/